# Showing the Following Set is Path Connected

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Would be grateful if someone could help me with the following question

"For any normed space $X$ which is NOT the set of Reals, the set $X$ (excluding $0$) is path connected

In the solutions the usual path $f(t)=(1-t)x+ty$ was used but they considered $y=cx$ where $c$ is a real number and $y$ Does NOT equal $cx$ . Why did they do this?

Answer (score 1):

They do this because if $y = cx$ then the usual path $f(t) = (1-t)x + ty$ could go through $0$: try this for $x = (1,1), y = (-2,-2)$ (so $c=-2$) in the plane.

And we want to show that $X \setminus \{0\}$ is path-connected so the path cannot go through $0$ because that's not a part of that space.

A more general argument: there are uncountably many different paths (even polygonal ones) between any two vectors $x \neq y$ that only have $x,y$ in common as endpoints and are disjoint in between. So we can even remove any countable set from $X$ and still get a path-connected remainder (as the countable set can only invalidate countably many of these paths).